# How can I specify that an object implements an interface in Java?

Tags: java

Consider the following two lines:

```
arr = (J[]) new Object[10];

public void add(J obj){
```

I want to specify here that J implements Comparable so I can write

```
while(arr[i] < obj)
```

How do I specify this?

Edit: David Wallace's answer looks correct, but I don't know how to appropriately scope the variable in the interface and class definitions.  Currently, they are:

```
public interface OrderedListADT<J> extends Iterable<J> {

public class OrderedVector<J> implements OrderedListADT<J>{
```

Comment: What is `J`?  A generic?  You could restrict the constraints with something like `<J extends Comparable>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're defining it at the class level, then you can write this:

```
public class OrderedVector<J extends Comparable<J>> implements OrderedListADT<J>
```

You *can* define it at the interface level in a similar way, if you wish to mandate that *all* users of this interface will insert in a `Comparable`, but defining it at the class level would work fine.

To further add, a class that implements `Comparable` only has the `compareTo` method (which returns a negative number, zero, or a positive number for less than, equal to, or greater than, respectively.  Java doesn't overload operators, so there wouldn't be any place for the less-than/greater-than symbols.

Answer (score 3):

If it implements `Comparable`, you can use its [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method (given an expression of the appropriate type). There is no syntax that will let you use the `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=` operators if an instance is of type `Comparable` (or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more details because it's not clear what your situation is.  However, suppose you have some class `MyClass` (perhaps an abstract class) that does not implement `Comparable`, but where you expect some subclasses of this class to implement `Comparable`.

```
public void add(MyClass obj) {
    ...
    ...
    // We execute some logic, and if we get to this point, we can be sure that obj is
    // *supposed* to be of a subclass that implements Comparable.

    if (((Comparable)obj).compareTo(otherObj) < 0) {
```

As shown above, you can use a cast to treat `obj` as a `Comparable`, and then you can use the `compareTo` method.  (You cannot use `<` directly on a `Comparable` in Java.)  If our assumption is wrong and `obj` really isn't a `Comparable`, then a `ClassCastException` will be thrown at run time.

You could also check beforehand like this:

```
    if (obj instanceof Comparable) {
        int comparison = ((Comparable)obj).compareTo(otherObj);
        ...
    } else {
        doSomethingUnusualBecauseObjIsntReallyComparable();
    }
```